# Token Input only works once i refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-tokeninput

So when i first go to a page where i use TokenInput, the tokeninput never hits my input form. Only after i refresh the page it works. Why is this and how can i make it work when i initially go the page?

When i first go to my page. Look at **players** field.

[image]

Once i refresh

[image]

I guess something happens to the javascript. Upon looking into the issue, it seems like the whole page loads with correct data for the date fields and checkbox. After i refresh the  correct data appears in my token input as it should, but with incorrect values for my checkbox and dates.

The dates and checkbox values belongs to **another** roster.

application.html

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "token-input-facebook", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery-tokeninput", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootsy
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery_nested_form

});

$(function() {
  $("#roster_player_tokens").tokenInput("/players.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#roster_player_tokens").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook",
    propertyToSearch: "gamertag",
    hintText: "Type in a gamertag",
    searchingText: "Searching...",
    tokenLimit: 4,
    preventDuplicates: true
  });
});
```

My rosters form

```
<%= form_for([@team, @roster]) do |f| %>
  <% if @roster.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@roster.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this roster from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @roster.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><li><%= msg %></li><% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <form role="form">

    <%= f.label :current %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :current %><br>

    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :start %><br>

    <%= f.label :end %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :end, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %><br>

  <%= f.label :player_tokens, "Players" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :player_tokens, "data-pre" => @roster.players.map(&:attributes).to_json %><br>

  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
  </form>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I have no experience with rails at all, so this may not be relevant, but if this was plain jQuery, then the `$.tokenInput()` function would need to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`. (If rails does this automagically, then this is of no use - but thought it was worth a mention.)

Comment: Thanks i used your example and put my script in my html file instead of application.js and it works better now. So the players field and all the other fields are correct on first page load. When i refresh the players field is the same (which it should, but now the other fields change to the rosters field that i was previously looking at. Anyways you can make an answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain better? Do you have multiple of these forms on a page? Do they all use the same html ID? That would break things...

Comment: To clarify: "but now the other fields change to the rosters field that i was previously looking at" is where you've lost me!

Comment: What you see in my images is the whole page, they use the same ID, but when i go from one roster to another and i refresh, i get data which is incorrect after refresh (only players field is the same). I think its because of turbo-links which was introduced in rails 4, im looking at this question right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links

Comment: Oh, I understand! Yes, that sounds like a Rails related problem...and that I really can't help with, apologies.

Comment: Well you helped with my initial question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was plain jQuery, then the `$.tokenInput()` function would need to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.

I'm not a rails user, but something similar should be done here also. The OP stated he "put [the] script in [the] html file instead of application.js", which did the job.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris is right  when I put my JavaScript code into HTML page at the bottom token-input works every time.

My ruby on rails slim _form.html.slim

```
.form-group.row
    .offset-sm-2.col-sm-10
      = f.submit class:'btn btn-primary pull-right', value: t('event.createevent_l')

javascript:
  $(function() {
    $('#event_friend_tokens').tokenInput('/friends.json', {
      crossDomain: false,
      prePopulate: $('#event_friend_tokens').data('pre'),
      theme: 'facebook',
      preventDuplicates: true,
      minChars: 2,
      tokenLimit: 10
    });
  });
```